# permission denied

Tags: command-line

I set the Java command to an alias in my `/home/.bashrc`.

```
alias java='/home/documents/jdk1.7/bin/java'.
```

However, typing `java` results in:

```
bash: /home/documents/jdk1.7/bin/java: permission denied
```

Comment: Whats the output of `ls -l /home/documents/jdk1.7/bin/java`?

Comment: sounds like a premissions problem .. I'm attempting to recreate the issue. I will let you know my findings

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you do not have permission to access or launch that file under the user you are launching it from.

Since you are using `alias` the user account accessing the shell needs to have the proper permissions to read/write or execute the file being referenced by the alias.

To test this you could `chmod -R a+rX /home/documents/jdk1.7` it should work ... this is not a recommended permission for it but at least that should narrow the problem down.

Comment: if you ran that command that basically made `java` read/write/execute for any user ... it only has to be ran once but again .. this can be a security risk because now anyone can run that file.

Comment: how to stop accessing the file for all users?